# How do I write a quasi quoter in terms of another quasi quoter

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

If I'm working with a third party quasi-quoter, for example `thirdParty :: QuasiQuoter`, and I want to write my own in terms of this quasi-quoter, how do I do this? In ghci I tried

```
runQ [| [thirdParty| |] |]
```

But this outputs (in my case):

```
LamE [VarP _render_2] (AppE (VarE GHC.Base.return) (ConE GHC.Tuple.()))
```

Which doesn't tell me what the abstract syntax tree for "[thirdParty| |]" is so it seems I can't construct such a patten with template Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is face-palmingly simple and I thought of it the moment I finished asking the question. There is nothing magical about `QuasiQuoter`. It's a plain old boring algebraic data type! Just do:

```
myQuasiQuoter = QuasiQuoter { quoteExp = f (quoteExp thirdParty) }
```

Where `f` is a function that transforms quasi-quoter as required. Do the same thing for `quotePat`, `quoteType`, and `quoteDec` if required.